# Add existing DB column to model with EF migration

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

In database there is a column `Created`, it has a default `GETDATE()` so it is assigned on insert automatically. This column is currently not in the model class. When I try to add the property to the model class:

```
[Required, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
public DateTime Created { get; set; }
```

and run `update-database`, it results in the message:

> Unable to update database to match the current model because there are
>   pending changes and automatic migration is disabled. Either write the
>   pending model changes to a code-based migration or enable automatic
>   migration. Set DbMigrationsConfiguration.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled to
>   true to enable automatic migration. You can use the Add-Migration
>   command to write the pending model changes to a code-based migration.

When I tried to allow automatic migration, EF tries to create the DB column `Created`, but this fails, because the column is already there.

Is there a way to correct the model class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the empty migration with `-IgnoreChanges` and apply to the database.

```
Add-Migration AddsCreatedProperty -IgnoreChanges
Update-Database
```

You would also want to add the column for any further databases you would bootstrap from your migrations. So in your empty migration add the sql statement in `Up` method

```
SQL(@"
    IF NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT *  FROM   sys.columns  WHERE  
        object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[MyTable]')  AND name = 'Created'
    )
    BEGIN
        ALTER TABLE MyTable
        ADD Created DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT (GETDATE());
    END
");
```